# How to start an elevated subprocess through QProcess on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, uac

I'm using the QProcess class to start a subprocess that performs a task. Sometimes the process needs administrator privileges. On Linux I simply run it through `pkexec` and everything just works. How can I accomplish the same effect on Windows?

To be clear: I want to be able to decide at runtime whether to run it as Administrator or not. I also need to be able to communicate with the process via stdin/stdout.

Or, to put it in code:

```
void modifyArgsForRoot(QString &program, QStringList &args)
{
#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    args.prepend(program);
    program = "pkexec";
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
    // what do I put here? //////////////////////////////
#endif
}

void foo()
{
    QProcess p;
    QString program;
    QStringList arguments;
    // ......
    if (!hasWriteAccessToCertainDir())
        modifyArgsForRoot(program, arguments);

    p.start(program, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Did you check other answers about running elevated executable from cmd or powershell? I think you'll have to go system specific, just as you do on linux.

Comment: Yes, none of them gave me a satisfying answer. Most suggest using ShellExecute function, but I want to go through QProcess.

Comment: pkexec is kind of a hack already though, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [`runas` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.10).aspx), which is somewhat of an alternative to `pkexec` for Windows.

For instance, you could try

```
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
    args.prepend(program);
    args.prepend("/user:mymachine\administrator"); // Change accordingly
    args.prepend("/noprofile"); // See link above
    program = "runas";
#endif
```

**Edit:** You could also try to use a manifest, as described [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/26725/how-to-ask-for-administrator-privileges-in-windows).

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work. AFAIK runas can't popup the UAC prompt, instead it wants to read the administrator password from the console.